# Simplifying HTML File Path in Quasar Electron Application

Tags: electron, quasar

I created an electron application using Quasar.

However, I want to display a web page using an HTML file within the application.

So, I used the 'asarUnpack' option in 'quasar.config' to place the folder containing the HTML file separately. I succeeded in opening it in a web browser when a specific button is clicked.

However, the path to the web page looks too complex and feels like exposing internal paths.
(e.g., file:///C:/Users/blahblah/blahblah/.../.../resources/app.asar.unpacked/manual/index.html)

To simplify the path, I want to place that folder directly under the app directory.

If you know how to do this, please let me know. I'm very new to Quasar, and I've been trying for a while but couldn't find a solution.

I attempted to copy files from 'app.asar.unpacked' directly under the 'app' directory via the 'quasar.config' file settings, but I failed.